# Reg Ex validates in Tets but not in IIS

Tags: c#, regex, iis, iis-7

I have the following Match expression:

```
((?:[a-z0-9\-]*\.){1,}[a-z0-9\-]*)/training/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/$
```

Which works for:

```
http://training.dev.local/training/xxxxxxx/
```

However when the rewrite rule is applied to the web config it is not recognised for a C# web application.

```
<rule name="Train redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="((?:[a-z0-9\-]*\.){1,}[a-z0-9\-]*)/training/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/$" ignoreCase="true" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="train-redirect/?code={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

I'm using regex101 to test: https://regex101.com/r/sL2nA6/3

Comment: Dosn't seem to handle mixed cases ín the url

Comment: <rule name="Train redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="((?:[a-z0-9\-]*\.){1,}[a-z0-9\-]*)/training/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/$" ignoreCase="true" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="train-redirect/?code={R:2}" />
        </rule>

Comment: What is your client side? Angularjs? Try `^.*((?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*\.)+[A-Za-z0-9-]*)/training/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/$`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module)  tutorial, it is shown that only the path in the URL is matched against the regular expression. Therefore, your regex can be written as:

```
^training/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/$
```

(ignore case rule is unnecessary with the above regex)

and the rewrite action should be changed accordingly to:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="train-redirect/?code={R:1}" />
```